# JSF 2.1.3 - IE 8 only - mojarra.ab(...) crash browser

Tags: jsf-2, internet-explorer-8

I have a page with this code (generated by JSF 2.1.3 running on Glassfish 3.1.1

```
<a class="pagenumber"
   onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'click',0,'main:coupon-all main:page-top main:page-bottom');return false"
   href="#"
   id="main:j_idt221:0:j_idt224">1</a>
```

This is generated from this part (inside a ui:repeat):

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="pagenumber">
  <f:ajax listener="#{productDetailInfoView.changePage(page)}"
          render=":main:page-top :main:page-bottom :main:coupon-all"/>#{page}
</h:commandLink>
```

Where:
`:main:page-top` is the ID of the top of the page navigation
`:main:page-bottom` is the ID of the bottom of the page navigation
`:main:coupon-all` is the ID of the ui:repeat that lists all the products in the page

### ISSUE:

On most browsers (as usual) and also IE 7 and IE 9, everything is just fine. But on IE8 (mostly on Windows XP but probably on Vista/8 too), the browser crashes and reload the page saying it has "recovered" it (sometimes shows the "Crash report" page and ask to send report to MS or cancel).

### Additional info:

I actually spent quite a lot of time debugging this, and the issue seems to be in the `jsf.js` (I use Stage: development to get the full version), in the ajax response part. But I couldn't find which precise part of it because after debugging the `jsf.ajax.request(...)` part then it's all asynchronous and I got stuck with nowhere to break-point. Sending the request seems ok as the browser crashes when this call completes.

Now the thing is that if I remove one of the element to re-render (either one of the navigation bar or the list of products), the remaining elements are rendered without error. However I need all the 3 elements rendered, not just two...

### EDIT: 12/07/05

I found that a highly connected item to the issue is [PIE.htc](http://css3pie.com/) for the round corners. Many of the elements in the 3 blocks I need to re-render have styleClass that use CSS like this:

```
.round {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  behavior: url('../PIE.htc');
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

The PIE.htc file is found and round corners are correctly displayed in IE7 and 8 as expected. However it makes the page very very slow on these IE browsers (I don't mind, I have been allowed to remove round corners for IE).
BUT the very weird thing is that if I simply remove all reference to PIE.htc in the CSS, then I still have the error. Maybe the other `border-radius` are creating issue. I am currently trying to remove any kind of round corner, even for all browsers and see where it leads.

My page is also XML validated.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: *"Now the thing is that if I remove one of the element to re-render (either one of the navigation bar or the list of products), the remaining elements are rendered without error"* is it one specific element or is it totally random? Have you also tried changing the order? Does any of those elements in turn contain some JavaScript code?

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue. Changing order: yes and it didn't help. `page-top` and `page-bottom` are similar small blocks of only h:commandLink and h:panelGroup. The third one is a big block that contains a javascript block. I will try removing it. However, I pushed further the test yesterday and found that PIE.htc was highly connected to the issue. See my edit for more details.

Comment: "is it one specific element or is it totally random": I can remove page-top form the list and the 2 others are rendered. If I remove coupon-all, the two others are rendered. Not exactly random because when there is only 2 items it doesn't crash anymore (but one item is left not updated)